# Twig file facebook in HWIOAuthBundle

Tags: facebook, symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

I am new with hwi / HWIOAuthBundle with symfony2.3 and FOSUserBundle.
I have already successfully install and this working fine with this doc https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697

But In on my twig page:

```
{% block content %}
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxxxxxxxx',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
        channelUrl : 'xxxxxxxxx',      // Channel file for x-domain comms
        status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
        xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });
};
// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
function fb_login() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // connected
            alert('Already connected, redirect to login page to create token.');
            document.location = "{{ url("hwi_oauth_service_redirect", {service:  "facebook"}) }}";
        } else {
            // not_authorized
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    document.location = "{{ url("hwi_oauth_service_redirect", {service: "facebook"}) }}";
                } else {
                    alert('Cancelled.');
                }
            }, {scope: 'email'});
        }
    });
}
</script>
<p>
<a href="#" onclick="fb_login();">Facebook Connect Button (Dialog)</a>
</p>
{# Bonus: Show all available login link in HWIOAuthBundle #}
{% render(controller('HWIOAuthBundle:Connect:connect')) %}
{% endblock %}
```

This page is show facebook logo when I click then show me facebook login page and after login redirect to again login page bcoz I set default redirect to login But My problem is after login no show facebook logout button ?

What I am doing ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the javascript way. Just give your path in  tag.

```
<a href="{{ url("hwi_oauth_service_redirect", {service: "facebook"}) }}">Facebook Connect Button (Dialog)</a>
```

Comment: @KunwarSiddharthSingh how do you solved without using the Gara method?